# Unable to update div with new content using call to API jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Been looking everywhere to try and solve this simple problem.  I am using an Ajax call in jQuery trying to replace '#newevent' with new data from the API.  I'm able to retrieve data successfully, but unable to replace the data with each call.  What happens is that the new data is just added to the bottom of the old data.  I've tried using $('#newevent').html('') and $('#newevent').empty() without success.  Any advice would be much appreciated!  Thanks

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<form id="query" action="away.php" method="get">
<label for="location">Location:</label>
<input type="text" id="location" name="location"/>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<h1>Welcome to Event Planner</h1>
<h2>The site where will help you plan upcoming events with what the weather is doing for that day!</h2>

<section id="container">
<div id="newevent"> 

</div>
</section>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="templates/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

scripts.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var newContent='';
var $content=$('#newevent');

$("#query").submit(function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    var url="http://api.eventful.com/json/events/search?app_key=XXXXXXXXX&";
    var url= url.concat(data);
    console.log(url);


$.ajax({
    url:url,
    dataType: 'jsonp',      
    success:function(response) 
    {
        $content.html("");
        $content.html(function()
            {
                for(var i=0; i<response.events.event.length; i++)
                {
                    newContent+=response.events.event[i].description;
                }
                return newContent;
            }).hide().fadeIn(400);  

    }

});
});


});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `newContent` is not being reset, set it as an empty string upon each call by doing `newContent = "";`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var newContent = '';
    var $content = $('#newevent');

    $("#query").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        var url = "http://api.eventful.com/json/events/search?app_key=XXXXXXXXX&";
        var url = url.concat(data);
        console.log(url);

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function (response)
            {
                newContent = ""; //Add this
                $content.html("");
                $content.html(function ()
                {
                    for (var i = 0; i < response.events.event.length; i++)
                    {
                        newContent += response.events.event[i].description;
                    }
                    return newContent;
                }).hide().fadeIn(400);

            }

        });
    });
});
```

or as @Jamiec pointed our in his comment, only declare it inside the html function callback:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $content = $('#newevent');

    $("#query").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        var url = "http://api.eventful.com/json/events/search?app_key=XXXXXXXXX&";
        var url = url.concat(data);
        console.log(url);

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function (response)
            {
                $content.html(function ()
                {
                    var newContent = "";
                    for (var i = 0; i < response.events.event.length; i++)
                    {
                        newContent += response.events.event[i].description;
                    }
                    return newContent;
                }).hide().fadeIn(400);

            }

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: or just remove the global variable and declare it only inside the `function()` where its being used.

Comment: Duh!  Oh wow, stupid mistake.  Thanks for the help taxicala and @Jamiec

Comment: No problem. Glad to help :)